# How to insert a asp:TabPanel inside a asp:Repeater?

Tags: repeater, tabpanel

When I try to execute the below code it gives me the error "There was an error rendering the control. Check to make sure all properties are valid".
Inner repeater works fine inside the tab container. But outer does not allow to have a tab panel within it.

Tab containers are not available in asp.net toolbox and therefore I installed Ajax tool kit and added that to Visual Studio and refer that Assembly as follows.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=1.0.11119.25966, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Repeater ID="ProjectRepeater" runat="server">
   <ItemTemplate>

    <cc1:TabContainer ID="TestTabContainer" runat="server">
            <cc1:TabPanel ID="TestTabPanel" HeaderText="technologies" runat="server">
             <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater id="SkillsRepeater" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="project-technologies" id="SkillZone" runat="server">
                                <a id="skill" href='<%# "http://vingo/Pages/projectresults.aspx?k="+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Skill")%>' target="_blank"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Skill")%></a>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate> 
                    </asp:Repeater>
             </ContentTemplate>
            </cc1:TabPanel>
          </cc1:TabContainer>
```

**EDIT:** Outer repeater code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="P" runat="server"> 
   <ItemTemplate> 
      <cc1:TabContainer ID="TTC" runat="server"> 
         <cc1:TabPanel ID="TTP" HeaderText="t" runat="server"> 
            <ContentTemplate> 
               <asp:Repeater id="A" runat="server">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                     <%--Code--%> 
                  </ItemTemplate> 
               </asp:Repeater> 
            </ContentTemplate> 
         </cc1:TabPanel> 
      </cc1:TabContainer> 
   </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Please add the code that shows the outer repeater.

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="P" runat="server">
       <ItemTemplate>
        <cc1:TabContainer ID="TTC" runat="server">
                <cc1:TabPanel ID="TTP" HeaderText="t" runat="server">
                 <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Repeater id="A" runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <%--Code--%>
                            </ItemTemplate> 
                        </asp:Repeater>
                 </ContentTemplate>
                </cc1:TabPanel>
              </cc1:TabContainer>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>

Comment: I see you are new to SO, so here's a little tip. It's best to add any additional code to your original answer so other users can benefit from it and possibly answer your question. Also, in the answer itself you can format the code rather than the way it appears in your comment now. I went ahead and updated your question for you.

Comment: `cc1:TabContainer` looks like it is a custom user control? Maybe the problem is in there. Can you post this code as well?

Comment: Appreciate your concern Shai, I've edited the question as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a asp.nett Repeater I could use the below code and it did the expected work of a asp.net Repeater and flexibility is much higher than when using asp:Repeaters

```
function JsonPCallBack(result) {

for (var technology in result) {
    $('body').append('<div OuterDiv id=OuterDivId><div class=project-technologies id=SkillZone><a id=skill href=http://vingo/Pages/projectresults.aspx?k=' +        technology + 'target=_blank></a></div>');

}
}
```